# Android - Reading all database entries to a listView

Tags: android, database, listview

I am trying to read all the database entries which I am trying to display in a list view. I am relatively new so I don't know which part I am messing up.

This is the class describing the database.

```
public class Item {

    public static final String TABLE = "ITEM";

    // Labels Table Columns names
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_EXPIRY = "expiry";

    // property help us to keep data
    public int item_ID;
    public String name;
    public int expiry;

}
```

This is the class with the DatabaseHelper

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //version number to upgrade database version
    //each time if you Add, Edit table, you need to change the
    //version number.
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "crud.db";

    public DBHelper(Context context ) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //All necessary tables you like to create will create here

        String CREATE_TABLE_ITEM = "CREATE TABLE " + Item.TABLE  + "("
                + Item.KEY_ID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
                + Item.KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + Item.KEY_EXPIRY + " INTEGER )";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ITEM);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed, all data will be gone!!!
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Item.TABLE);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

Now I want to read all the database entries and populate a list view using an onCreate() in an activity -  so that when I call that activity, the list is displayed.

```
public class ItemShow extends ListActivity {

TextView item_Id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_show);



}
```

What is the best way to do that? I tried searching a lot but none of the solutions seem to work.

Thank you :)

Comment: Just Posted an answer , and remind you before you call GetAllItem() function you have to populate your table with data by yet creating another function that add row data into table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First query your database using a Cursor:

```
Cursor c = db.query(TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

You should research what each param is for a cursor query, but basically if you're doing a SELECT * with no WHERE then it'll look like the above.

It's best to created a Model for your database table. So have a model class called something like, Entry, for example.

```
public class Entry {
  public String id;
  public String name;
  public String expiry;
}
```

Then like L-X's answer, loop through the cursor, but then just map the results to your model.

In DatabaseHelper:

```
public function getEntries() {
    List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
       if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            entries.add(createEntryFromCursor(c));

        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
    return entries;
}


public Entry createEntryFromCursor(Cursor c) {
    if (c == null)
        return null;

    Entry item = new Entry();

    item.id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID));
    item.name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME));
    item.expiry = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EXPIRY));

    return item;

}
```

Then you create an ListAdaptor that uses your Entry model and populate that adaptor in your activity.

So create a custom EntryListAdapter:

```
public class EntryListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Entry> {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context mContext;

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView id, name, expiry;
}

public EntryListAdapter(Context context, List<Entry> entries){
    super(context, R.id.row, entries);
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entries_list_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.id = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_id);
        holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
        holder.expiry = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_expiry);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

        Entry entry = getItem(position);
        holder.id.setText(entry.id);
        holder.name.setText(entry.name);
        holder.expiry.setText(entry.expiry);
    }

    return convertView;
  }
}
```

Then in your activity:

```
    private ListView mListView;
    private EntriesListAdapter mAdapter;

    mListView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    mAdapter = new EntryListAdapter(getActivity(),  databaseHelper.getEntries());
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int pos, long id) {
            Entry entry = (Entry)listView.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        }

    });
```

Future note: You may want to look into querying the DB on it's own thread depending on the size of the database and the responsiveness of your views.

Answer (score 0):

You can have ArrayList that extends a CustomClass also that stores each data into different variable. Define this inside your DBHelper

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllItem(){
    ArrayList<String> allItem = new ArrayList<>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+Item.TABLE;
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String data="";
            data += cursor.getInt(0);
            data += cursor.getString(1);
            data += cursor.getInt(2);

            allItem.add(data);

        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return allItem;
}
```

And then call in your MainActivity

```
DBHelper dbTools = new DBHelper(this);
ArrayList<String> itemList = dbTools.getAllItem();
```

Comment: I would not recommend to query the DB in the UI thread, as you're suggesting with your answer. The cursor must be closed at the end of the query. If you just need a query, why you call `getWritableDatabase()` instead of `getReadableDatabase()`?

Comment: Can you tell me the reason why it should not be on main UI thread and what should I use Handler /Aysnc Task?

Comment: Because potentially you could get a ANR if your query is 'heavy' or you have tons of data to select. Use Loaders (CursorLoader in this case), they have been designed for this and read the tutorial I've posted in my answer.

Comment: Wait ,let me compete the tutorial , just completed section 4 of it